# The behaviour of the bounds of $P(X \geq \frac{(n+1)}{2} + r\sqrt{n})$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability, limits, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a natural number chosen uniformly at random from $1, . . . , n$. I'd like to see how the bounds of $P(X \geq \frac{(n+1)}{2} + r\sqrt{n})$ behave as $n \to \infty$ for some value of $r > 0$. First, I need to obtain the bounds using Markov's and Chebyshev's inequality.

This is how I did it:
If $X$ is a natural number chosen uniformly at random from $1, . . . , n$, then $P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{n}, P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{n}, \dotsc, P(X = n) = \frac{1}{n}$. So,

$$E(X) = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n-1}{2}$$
and
$$E(X^2) = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j^2}{n} = \frac{1}{6}(2n^2+3n+1).$$
Therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X) &= E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{6}(2n^2+3n+1) - \frac{(n-1)^2}{4}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6} - \frac{(n-1)^2}{4}\\
&= \frac{2(n+1)(2n + 1) - 3(n-1)^2}{12}\\
&= \frac{n^2+12n-1}{12}
\end{align}
Now,
$$P(X \geq \frac{(n+1)}{2} + r\sqrt{n}) = P(X - \frac{(n-1)}{2} \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n})$$
since $\frac{(n+1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1+1+1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1)}{2} + 1$. Because $1 + r\sqrt{n}$, I can use Chebyshev's inequality in the following manner
\begin{align}
P(X - \frac{(n-1)}{2} \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n}) &= P(|X - \frac{(n-1)}{2}| \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n})\\
&\leq \frac{\text{Var(X)}}{(1+r\sqrt{n})^2}\\
&= \frac{n^2+12n-1}{12(1+r\sqrt{n})^2},
\end{align}
which is the bounds for $P(X \geq \frac{(n+1)}{2} + r\sqrt{n})$. But when I plot the bounds, all I can conclude is that the bound goes to infinity (when $n \to \infty$) for small $r$. For large $r$, it seems that the bound goes to $0$ (also when $n \to \infty$). Am I doing the calculation correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one error in your calculations but it isn't an important one. It is in the equality
\begin{equation}
    P(X - \frac{(n-1)}{2} \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n}) = P(|X - \frac{(n-1)}{2}| \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n})
\end{equation}
Consider $n = 25$ and $r = 1$ so that
$$P(X - \frac{(n-1)}{2} \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n}) = P(X - 12 \geq 6) = P(X \geq 18) = 8/25$$
while
$$P(|X - \frac{(n-1)}{2}| \geq 1 + r\sqrt{n}) = P(|X - 12| \geq 6) = P(X \in \{1,2,...,6\}\cup\{18,19,...,25\}) = 14/25$$
In general the second bound should be just a bit less than double the first. However, this doesn't change the fact that the limit in the bound from Chebyshev goes to $+\infty$, this is because Chebyshev is often quite a loose bound when applied near the expected value. Let me make this precise.

One way of stating Chebyshev's inequality is that
\begin{equation}
   P(|X - EX| > k) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{k^2}
\end{equation}
When $k << \sqrt{Var(X)}$ then
\begin{equation}
   1 <<\frac{Var(X)}{k^2} 
\end{equation}
and we see that Chebyshev becomes a very bad bound. Now let's look at $k$ and $Var(X)$ when $n$ becomes very large.

\begin{align}
    k &= 1 + r\sqrt{n} \approx r\sqrt{n} \\
    \sqrt{Var(X)} &= \sqrt{(n^2 + 12n - 1)/12} \approx \frac{n}{12}
\end{align}
(remember I'm using $n$ big enough that everything else doesn't contribute much). From this we see that for large $n$ (unless $r$ is also very large)
\begin{equation}
    k \approx r\sqrt{n} << \frac{n}{12} \approx \sqrt{Var(X)}
\end{equation}
and we see that the bound from Chebyshev really should be quite a bad bound when $n$ is big (unless as you pointed out $r$ is also big).

Comment: About your correction, does that mean that the probability without the absolute value is smaller or equal than the probability with the absolute value? Is it true only in my case or in general?

Comment: It's always the case that  for any random variable $X$ and $t \geq 0$ that $P(X \geq t) \leq P(|X| \geq t)$ since $P(|X| \geq t) = P(X \geq t) + P(X \leq -t) \geq P(X \geq t)$